# How to make a php variable equal to the result of mysql_fetch_array?

Tags: php, mysql

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM fruit WHERE color='red' ");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    echo $row['name']."|" ;// this echo apple|strawberry|cherry     
}
```

How to make a php variable equal to the result of mysql_fetch_array? I need to make a equal like: `$newname="apple|strawberry|cherry"`, so that I can use the new variable `$newname` for another process. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than echo, concatenate:

```
$newname = '';
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    $newname .= $row['name']."|" ;// this echo apple|strawberry|cherry     
}
$newname = rtrim($newname,'|');
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$newname .= $row['name']."|" ;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM fruit WHERE color='red' ");

$newname= '';

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    $newname.= $row['name']."|" ;  
}
```

This gives you a string $newname like you want.

Answer (score 0):

I know everyone else went with string concatenation, but I would personally suggest an array push followed by a join - I haven't benchmarked it, but I believe it would perform slightly better.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
     $newname[] = $row['name'];
}
echo join('|', $newname);
```

Answer (score 0):

i use  this in my joomla :

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query->select('price');
$query->from($db->quoteName('#__google_api'));
$query->where($db->quoteName('id')." = ".$db->quote('1'));
// Reset the query using our newly populated query object.
$db->setQuery($query);

$db->setQuery($query);
$price = $db->loadResult();
```

Fetches data for a single colume and stores it in `$price`